# stopping a higher order function generating numbers at certain number

Tags: javascript

I have a function that takes another function that generates consecuitive numbers

(numbers can be generated from any start point)

also the function takes a value which it should stop before

i can get it to work from zero up to the required limit but not if for expample it starts at 1

these are requirements:

returns a function on first invocation
✓ returns given value on first call
✓ Subsequent invocations emits consecutive integers (1 ms)
✓ exclusively emits undefined when surpassed limit (not inclusive) (1 ms)
✕ exclusively emits undefined when surpassed limit (not inclusive) when generator does not start at 0

```
hof.to = function (funcfrom, n) {
  counter = n;
  return function () {
    if (counter > 0) {
      counter--;
      return funcfrom();
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Have you been forbidden from using [generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator)?

Comment: `counter` being a global variable looks like a bad idea. Otherwise, it's unclear what the problem is without seeing the code of the test cases (especially the failing one), you have not shown how the method is called.